# How to track Facebook appRequest that send from Unity app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I want to track invites that send from "player_1" to other players to count them and as result give "player_1" some reward. Like in PVZ2.

Ok, Facebook have SDK for Unity3d. Here is API to call App request dialog that allow to invite player:

```
public static void AppRequest(
        string message,
        string[] to = null,
        string filters = "",
        string[] excludeIds = null,
        int? maxRecipients = null,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",
        FacebookDelegate callback = null)
```

Facebook doc says something about redirect_url that could be used to track user's that accept indentations:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

But Unity plugin doesn't have this param.

Also doc says that follow:

> Requests are only available for games on Facebook.com or iOS and
>   Android apps. Accepting a request from a game will direct the person
>   to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request. For native
>   mobile apps, accepting the request will direct the person to the app
>   on their device if installed or to the appropriate location (Apple App
>   Store or Google Play) to download the app otherwise.

Game is going to work on mobile devices only. Therefore we don't need to make Facebook Canvas application. Should I implement this Canvas URL script on our website anyway?

Where is the correct place to inject code (server side script) to track Facebook app requests?

UPDATE:
Thanks to Bhavesh Vadalia for answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597185/425707
I've decided to not handle friends requests in Canvas App. 
Here is solution for Facebook SDK 5.0.3:

```
// Quesry string: "/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1";
string q = "/fql?q=SELECT+uid,+name,+is_app_user,+pic_square+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+AND+is_app_user+=+1";
FB.API(q, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, friendsResult =>
{
    if (friendsResult.Error != null)
    {
        FbDebug.Error(friendsResult.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        FbDebug.Log(friendsResult.Text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is implement for track code using facebook graph api implement in for my application. hope it also help to you.

I am using facebook 3.6 sdk

```
private void requestMyAppFacebookFriends(Session session) {
        Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
        friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                List<GraphUser> friends = getResults(response);

                Log.e("RESULT : ", "@"+friends.size());

                for(int i =0;i<friends.size(); i++){

                    GraphUser user = friends.get(i);
                    boolean installed = false;
                    if(user.getProperty("installed") != null){
                        installed = (Boolean) user.getProperty("installed");
                    }
                    if(installed){
                        Log.e("USER NAME", "@"+friends.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }
                // TODO: your code here
            }
        });
        friendsRequest.executeAsync();
    }
 private Request createRequest(Session session) {
        Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

        Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "picture","installed" };
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

        Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
        parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
        request.setParameters(parameters);

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: The main question is "How to track appRequests". There is no problem in sending requests, but how to count them? Should I make Canvas application to handle it, then how to redirect Canvas App to AppCenter page? Or is there are any other solution?

Comment: Sorry to say it's not your ans. Above is my application code which i am using. In this above code i am getting all member which are using my application.

Comment: Does param "installed" respond that application is installed on IOS/Android device?

Comment: Yes, whatever created app in developers.facebook. this app_id through filter your friend.